# How to create a dashboard in Visual Studio from a SQL query (.sql file)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I am trying to generate a dashboard in Visual Studio based on a SQL 'New Query' (*i.e. not from a .bak file*).

Could someone help me "link" Visual Studio to my SQL query...
The database does not appear in Visual Studio '*Connect to a database*' dropdown list, despite entering the correct data source and the correct server name (the connection is successful).

*Note:
I tried renaming a copy of the file .bak instead of .sql and placing it in the 'MSSQL\Backup folder'. This "DIY" solution does not seem to work either.*

FYI - *in case this is relevant* - I am using

- the latest version of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (Release number: 18.6)
- Visual Studio 2019 ('Community' version)

Comment: You don't "link" Visual Studio to query. You create Data Connection managers or Connection strings and use those to execute queries. You don't link to a specific query.

Comment: Hi Larnu. Thank you for your answer.I am not sure I fully understand what you are referring to. I am trying to create a dashboard on Visual Studio based on a SQL script that runs in SQL. Note: the 'Restore Database' option in SQL indicates 'No backupset selected to be restored'. If I try to use the artificially created .bak file I obtain 'An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch', which makes the 'OK' button inaccessible.